# If 4 things are true then do ____ . Having a hard time with the If statement and it checking if 4 values are true to execute the code

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic, boolean-logic, multiple-conditions

```
   if (test1 === 'hi' && test2 === 'bye' && test3 = 'joe' && test4 === 'sam') {  

console.log("all 4 statements are true!!);
      };
```

getting an r value error which im assuming is syntax. Could someone help me what would be the correct format/method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (test1 === 'hi' && test2 === 'bye' && test3 === 'joe' && test4 === 'sam') {  
  console.log("all 4 statements are true!!");
}
```

Comment: test3 = 'joe' is an assignment!

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a double quote
What I like to do is install prettier, when you cannot format your code, it's mean there are some syntaxs that's are not correct